# gcc and glibc versions

Tags: c, linux, gcc, centos, glibc

I have gcc 4.1.2 installed. I installed a new separate gcc (version 4.4.6) too using yum on CentOS. Now my question is, do these two gcc versions use the same glibc version or glibc is different for both of them? How can I find out? Secondly, is it better to have a newer version of glibc in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2):

Both GCC versions will use the glibc version you have installed on your system. GCC packages don't (usually) ship a separate C library.

Comment: Probably not. Unless you've profiled your app, determined that a glibc function was a bottleneck, _and_ that function has been updated/rewritten in the newer version. Generally, you might notice some improvement in some apps, but don't expect anything spectacular.

Comment: But I think it would depend which version of gcc the glibc was compiled with, as I find that newer gcc versions perform optimization better or no?

Comment: Newer gcc versions have better optimizers, yes. Compiling anything, including glibc, with better optimizers can improve performance, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple program which makes a call to a glibc function. Then compile it with both versions of gcc and then do `ldd a.out` on each compilation. You'll get the list of libraries used.

If your source file is `test.c` then:

```
$ gcc test.c -o out1  # with gcc 4.1.2
$ gcc test.c -o out2  # with gcc 4.4.6 
$ ldd out1
$ ldd out2
```

This will show the libc versions used by each gcc.

Performance may or may not be better depending on the update done for glibc functions.